# Datetime in WHERE clause

Tags: query, datetime, dbamp, where

I am facing issue with Datetime column in WHERE clause. Below two queries are giving different counts.

```
SELECT COUNT(CallTime_c) FROM SF...TableName WHERE CallDateTime > '09-13-2018 09:01:00' and CallDateTime < '09-13-2018 09:05:00'

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(SF,'SELECT COUNT(CallTime_c) FROM TableName WHERE CallDateTime > 2018-09-13T09:01:00Z AND CallDateTime < 2018-09-13T09:05:00Z')
```

Comment: Are you using a third party tool to run these queries, or perhaps working in Marketing Cloud? The first query you've provided isn't valid SOQL (the query language supported by Apex/Sales Cloud/etc...).

Answer (score 2):

This strikes me as expected behavior rather than an issue.

The ISO 8601 datetime format `2018-09-13T09:01:00Z` breaks down like this:

- Year: 2018
- Month: 9
- Day: 13
- Hour: 9
- Minute: 1
- Second: 0
- *Time zone*: Z (i.e. "Zulu" time, UTC+0)

The time zone is the key here. When you specify the datetime in the other format (From what I know, DBAmp uses T-SQL) you've listed `09-13-2018 09:01:00`, the timezone is not present, and the DBAmp documentation makes it sound like it assumes you're specifying *local* times by default.

If you're not in the UTC+0 time zone, then it's not at all surprising that those two different queries would return different results, *because you are actually querying for records that fall under different datetime ranges*

Probably the easiest solution here is to adjust your "openquery" SOQL query to specify your timezone. If I were doing this, being in Minnesota, USA where we're currently UTC-5, the datetime string I'd be using is "2018-09-13T09:01:00-0500"

Adjust according to your own UTC timezone